# (react-three-fiber) I want to import a 3D model and then load an image on it

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

How do I do that? Image loading a cup and then let the user select an image to show on it.

Similar to this article `https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/11/threejs-react-three-fiber/` but letting me specify the image

Answer (score 0):

Try, importing your texture image to the component from your src or public folder. Then use the new THREE.TextureLoader() to use with your mesh.

Since you want the user to be able to add an image, use an input type . Save the user's image to the state and apply it the same way using new THREE.TextureLoader() and a mesh. If the images are yours, then import all of the images, store them all in the state, and create an onClick for your mesh that changes the texture file on the mesh to an image that is in the state.

Else,

If its a .gltf or .glb model i recommend the [GLTFJSX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gltfjsx) npx command. Simply add your 3d model to the public folder, cd into the public folder, install @react-three/drei then run [npx @react-three/gltfjsx "modelname.gltf or .glb" NamedMe.js]. This is the most optimal way to import a model into WEBGL since .gltf filetype is heavily optimized. When you use this command it automatically imports your meshes, materials, groupings, refs, and properties for your 3d models. Use this [website](https://products.aspose.app/3d/conversion/fbx-to-gltf) to convert your obj or fbx to .gltf/glb. But this website won't "bake,attach,integrate" your texture maps inside the file as many 3d softwares do.

If it's an OBJ, then use this guy's example: [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/x7byw8-forked-9hk96) from code sandbox, it shows you how to use the OBJ loader from three/examples to import your OBJ.